# Update flowfile attributes(Filename,FileSize,Time) into Postgres Table Using NiFi

Tags: apache-nifi

we want to insert flowfile attributes(Filename,FileSize,Time) into Postgres Table Using NiFi

Comment: Sharing some of your code that you are currently trying to get working would help, or what you have tried so far.

Comment: I have used below list of processor in sequence

1. ListFiles
2. UpdateAttribute
3. AttributeToCSV
4. PutRecord



After further debugging i have found that  AttributeToCSV is not giving expected result.

Answer (score 1):

Use below processors in sequence

1. ListFiles
2. UpdateAttributes
3. Put SQL

In Put Sql one can create insert queries which are required for attributes and it will update PSQL Table